# pick data from partitioned tables based on date. If date is specified automatically the data for that date range should be picked from correct table

Tags: netezza

I have partitioned tables based on timestamp.
That is data for a month is kept separately in a table.
Eg: impression_201501,impression_201502 corresponds to data of 2015 jan and 2015 feb respectively.
I have a requirement of pulling exceptions on a biweekly basis automatically.

So when I pull exceptions for the last week of jan and 1st week of feb, (14 days biweekly)how to get netezza pull the data from impression_201501 and impression_201502 automatically?

Comment: Typically, one does not do range partitioning across tables in a Netezza system.  Is there a particular requirement you have for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider compiling these into a single table, especially if they have the exact same table structure. If you want to be sure that each of the values is distributed, just add the timestamp as part of your distribution key (though you should consider the impact of this when attempting to join to the table).

That said, the only way I know to achieve what you want is to use a stored procedure that returns a [reftable](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_returning_a_result_set.html). Then you could create a stored procedure like so.

```
create or replace procedure biweekly_data() 
returns reftable(biweekly_table) language nzplsql as
begin_proc
  declare this_month varchar;
  declare last_month varchar;
  declare sql varchar;

  begin
    this_month := extract(year from current_date) 
      || lpad(extract(month from current_date),2,'0');
    last_month := extract(year from current_date - 1) 
      || lpad(extract(month from current_date - 1),2,'0');
    sql := 'insert into ' || reftablename
      || ' select * ' --Your select statement will vary.
      || ' from impression_' || this_month
      || ' union select * '
      || ' from impression_' || last_month;
    execute immediate sql;
    return reftable;
  end;
end_proc;
```

Not tested, so you may need to tweak a bit.